# setData always returns False

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt

I use a custom QTableView and a custom QSqlTableModel in my gui.
What I want to do is to define a slot "markOneRead", which will turn a boolean to false when the user click on a row. My database is defined like this:

a title | ...some fields... | the_boolean

The database is a Sqlite one.

What I want to do is basically a read/unread system. When the line has never been clicked, the boolean is set to True. When the line is clicked, the boolean turns False.

But I can't manage to turn the boolean to False. Here is what I do:

```
def markOneRead(self, element):

    """Slot to mark an article read"""

    new = self.tableau.model().index(element.row(), 12).data()

    if new == "false":
        return
    else:

        new_index = self.tableau.model().index(element.row(), 12)

        print(self.modele.setData(new_index, False))
```

And it always prints False (so the setData methode did not work).

Here is my implementation of my model:

```
class ModelPerso(QtSql.QSqlTableModel):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ModelPerso, self).__init__()

    def setQuery(self, query):

        self.query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
        self.query.prepare(query.executedQuery())
        self.query.exec_()

        results = QtSql.QSqlTableModel.setQuery(self, self.query)

        while self.canFetchMore():
            self.fetchMore()
        return results


    def select(self):

        results = QtSql.QSqlTableModel.select(self)

        while self.canFetchMore():
            self.fetchMore()
        return results


    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.EditRole):

        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            return super(QtSql.QSqlTableModel, self).setData(index, value, role)
```

Could you give me a hand please ?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something but inside `print` should be `self.tableau.model().setData(new_index, False)` isn't it?

Comment: That's the same thing, because self.tableau.model() and self.modele returns the same object.

Comment: have you checked to see that the `data()` return value is a boolean? it looks like you are treating it as a string in your `if` statement. As a string you should be doing `setData(some_index, "False")`

Comment: That's weird, because type(data()) returns "str". So you're right, the return value is a string. But in my db (sqlite), the field is an integer (there is no boolean type in sqlite). When I open my db, there is "true" or "false" as values, where it is supposed to be 0 and 1. Somewhere else in my code, I set this value with True or False, and sqlite is supposed to do the conversion by itself. I tried setData(some_index, "False"), as you suggested, but it didn't work. There is something I'm missing with sqlite and PyQt.